# Submit button not showing in certain case (e-mail)

Tags: html

I got a problem with an email form during a survey with test users.

```
 <form style="text-align: center; margin: 25px 0;" method="post" action="https://url.de/user/registration/activated?user=${req.body.username}">
     <input type="hidden"/>
     <button type="submit" style="some styling">Bitte hier klicken
     </button>
</form>
```

It just happens with one user but in his mailing service the button is just displayed as text and he can't click on it. Is there an alternative to this form button method? With an a-tag it's not working.

Comment: Some e-mail clients do not support showing mail as HTML. Maybe you could try sending other HTML elements (not related to forms), to check if this is the case?

Comment: I've just taken a look at [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/forms-in-email/) article which says that Outlook doesn't support using HTML forms in emails. As @LarsKristensen said, its not guaranteed that all email clients will support it. The article (and I) recommend hyper-linking the user to a web page where they can then fill out the form instead

Comment: you can't use [form](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/how-forms-perform-in-html-emai/#:~:text=The%20short%20of%20it%20is,be%20able%20to%20use%20it.), check the supported tags [here](https://www.pinpointe.com/blog/email-campaign-html-and-css-support), you should replace it with an `<a>` tag.

Comment: @LS_ It's working with gmail and outlook. The a tag doesn't work cause I get a cannot get error when trying to submit to my backend.

Comment: @Orange many other [clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/how-forms-perform-in-html-emai/#:~:text=Complete%20Results) doesn't support the `form` tag. Edit the backend in order to accept GET requests for that specific webservice, if possible.

Comment: @LS_ All right thanks. I'd rather create a frontend page then with a separate link for registration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your html like this:

```
 <form style="text-align: center; margin: 25px 0;" method="post" action="https://url.de/user/registration/activated?user=${req.body.username}">
     <input type="hidden"/>
     <input type="submit" style="some styling" value="Bitte hier klicken" />
</form>
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Sadly it's not working with that specific mail service.
Also not responding to a click.